# How to make an element appear only when scrollbar is present?

Tags: css, scrollbar

Hi,

I need certain pseudoelement to appear ONLY when the scrollbar appears. This is the code:

```
.pseudo::before, .pseudo::after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    content: "";
    width: 18px;
    height: calc(100% - 2px);
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
    border: 5px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pseudo::before {background: rgba(177, 171, 44, 0.4);border-radius: 25px;}
```

But this lines of code are only necessary as the scrollbar appears. No need to have it when its not present.

A CSS only solution would be nice but I am open to alternatives.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to observe the element's size, and see if a scrollbar appears, and add a class to it if does. The pseudo-element would only appear if the class exists on their parent. The demo uses the new [ResizeObserver](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver). Currently supported only by Chrome. However, there's a [pollyfill](https://github.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill).

Drag the text area handle down to enlarge it 'till a scrollbar appears.

**Note:** after your pseudo-elements appear they cause a permanent overflow, so you can't hide the scrollbar by shrinking the text area..

```js
const ro = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  const { target } = entries[0];
 const hasScrollbar = target.scrollHeight > target.clientHeight;
  
  if(hasScrollbar) target.classList.add('has-scrollbar');
  else target.classList.remove('has-scrollbar');
});

ro.observe(document.querySelector('.pseudo'));
```

```css
.pseudo {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 150px;
}

.pseudo.has-scrollbar::before, .pseudo.has-scrollbar::after {
  display: block;
}

.pseudo::before,
.pseudo::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
  width: 18px;
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 5px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pseudo::before {
  background: rgba(177, 171, 44, 0.4);
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pseudo">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dapibus ante ac iaculis dapibus. Vestibulum quis purus at urna tincidunt commodo ac id ante.
  <br />
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I need a Firefox solution.